# New Issue Panel in Jira

Tags: jira-plugin

I'm beginner in Jira development and I'm trying to build custom panel under panel "description" for all issues with my iframe. There is iframe will include widget with another resource.
How can I build it by Atlassian SDK?

I built it in panel Jira Issue Details such as "custom field", but I've not found how it's file make like iframe.